# Can 'jQuery' & 'Javascript' coexist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am planning to use 'jQuery' for my WSS 3.0 Site. I am using 'Javascript' also on it.

Will I face any conflicts?

Thnks
--saumil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery is just a library of code written -in- JavaScript. So in order to use jQuery you actually need use to JavaScript. So to answer your question: no, there will be no conflicts as JQuery needs JavaScript to work.

Comment: Thx Erwin for the answer